# Using color picker in plugin, does input attribute order matter?

Tags: plugins, php, jquery, ajax, color-picker

I'm trying to use the WP color picker in a plugin admin menu and it doesn't seem to be doing anything at all. I'm following the directions here: http://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/11/30/new-color-picker-in-wp-3-5/

This is how it is setup:

cbs-admin-menu.php:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'mw_enqueue_color_picker' );
function mw_enqueue_color_picker( $hook_suffix ) {
    // first check that $hook_suffix is appropriate for your admin page
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script-handle', ECBS_JS_URL . 'my-script.js', array(     'wp-color-picker' ), false, true );
}
```

my-script.js:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($j){
    $j('.my-color-field').wpColorPicker();
});
```

In the admin menu there is a drop down box where the user picks the name of a template they want to edit. I'm using AJAX .post() to build the edit form and dynamically update a div to display it.

This is the code that builds the form fields:

```
return ecbs_get_label( $ecbs_style_data[ECBS_STYLE_NAME], $ecbs_style_data[ECBS_NICE_NAME] ) .
    '<input type = "text" name="' . $ecbs_style_data[ECBS_STYLE_NAME] . '" ' .
    'value="' . $ecbs_style_value . '" ' .
    (($ecbs_style_data[ECBS_VALUE_TYPE] === 'hex') ? 'class="my-color-field"'  : 
    'onLoad="this.value=\'' . $ecbs_style_value . '\'" ') .
    '> ';
```

When I look at my source, I can verify that it has the correct `class="my-color-field"` attribute. The weird thing is, the `type="text"` attribute is at the end, even though it is not formatted that way in my code. This is what the outputted HTML looks like:

```
<label for="background-color">Background Color</label><input name="background-color" value="#997766" class="my-color-field" type="text"> <br>
```

Could the type attribute being at the end cause an issue with this script? I wouldn't think so, but I can't figure out what else might be wrong.

When I look at the source, I can verify that my-script.js is linked and the url is correct.

---

Edited to add the code from my other .js file. Maybe something conflicting between them?

cbs-edit-options.js

```
// This script sends the id of the selected template to the php
// function ecbs_populate_admin_template() and then sends the
// formatted response to the ecbs-edit-area div in the admin
// submenu.
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j("select").change(function() {
        var str = "";
        $j("select option:selected").each(function() {
        str = $j("select").val();
        try {
            $j.post( ajaxurl, {
                data: { template : str },
                action: 'ecbs_populate_admin_template'
            }, function ( response ) {
                //alert(response);
                $j("#ecbs-edit-area").html( response );
            }
                    );
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert(err);
        }
        });
    })
        .change();
});
$j(function() {
    $j( document ).tooltip();
});
```

This script works fine.

I did try moving the contents of my-script.js to this file and enqueueing it instead, but that did not make a difference.

Comment: This is not how you use [tag:ajax] in WordPress. Take a look at these [examples](https://gist.github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/6902888)

Comment: What I did is the exact instructions from the WordPress post I linked to. I have been able to use AJAX without any problem in my other application. I just can't get the native color picker to work.

Comment: Do you have errors in your console? If so: [edit] and add please.

Comment: No errors. Nothing. It doesn't do anything at all. I've basically given up on it at this point.

Comment: Could you  try switching to an ID instead of a class?

Comment: I just did that, but no change. I'm wondering if the color picker is conflicting with my other .js script. I wouldn't even begin to know how to tell.

Comment: Make all your above code a separate plugin. Test it in a plain vanilla local install :)

Comment: I'll give that a try once I get this plugin finished and see what happens. Thanks for the help.